# How to get SharePoint Farm Architecture of UAT/Test & Production Environment from Central Administration or elsewhere in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: central-administration, farm-setup

How to get **SharePoint Farm Architecture of UAT/Test & Production Environment** from Central Administration or elsewhere in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

In Central Administration, you can see the "Manage Servers in farm". This displays servers, their roles and a summary of services running on each server.

You can also view Search Topology through Search Administration.

However, there is no content in Central admin which displays complete architecture information.

That's where visio or 3rd party product comes in. :)

Here are some [articles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx) with some diagrams which may help you get started. (also [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123594.aspx))

Comment: Thanks!! Russell..your answer was useful to me. Just a query, from where can I view the Search Topology. I could not find the Search Administration.

Comment: Glad to help. :) If you have configured search, click Application Management -> Manage Service Applications -> Search service application (or similar).

Comment: Thanks a lot..Russell!! you solved my query and requirement :-) It was a huge help!!

Comment: Glad to help, mark this as answer if it answered your question, thanks